# Is is possible to programmatically change the resourceProviderFactoryType?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, globalization

I have a custom implementation of `IResourceProvider` and `ResourceProviderFactory`. Now the default way of making sure ASP.NET uses these custom types is to use the web.config and specify the factory like so:

```
<globalization resourceProviderFactoryType="Product.Globalization.TranslationResourceProviderFactory" />
```

This works perfectly, except that in my resource provider I need database access. I want to use my IoC-container(Ninject) to inject the repositories needed to access this data into the CustomResourceProvider. But how am I going to do this? I have no control over the instantiation of the factory, so the factory can't get a reference to my IoC.

Is there any way to register a custom provider programmatically, in for example the Global.asax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom implementation of `ResourceProviderFactory` could use the DI framework to retrieve the instance of `IResourceProvider`.

Comment: Yes, but how do I get a reference to my DI framework? I think it's an anti-pattern to make my "kernel" statically available in some singleton class.

Comment: There doesn't really seem to be another way, i've used the WCF implementation at http://github.com/idavis/ninject.extensions.wcf/blob/master/source/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf/KernelContainer.cs to do this. Thanks for you input.